# How to add moving “bubble” animation to CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I’m trying to recreate the scope bar used in the Music app in iOS. When you tap on one of the cells the selection moves from one cell to the other.

I’m assuming this is done by moving the background view from the currently selected cell to the new one then making the background view appear on the new selected cell the immediately moving that old view back to create that illusion.

I tried this but the problem is if for example cell 0 is selected and you scroll to select the last cell and cell 0 is now off the screen. Cell 0 gives a nil value since (if I’m correct in saying the system destroys the cells off screen).

(Code to follow)

[image: Music App Example]

Comment: You could trying following this guide: https://medium.com/@namratasims/liquid-bubble-swipe-effect-animation-with-collectionview-5b1ca83f16bc

Comment: @CedanMisquith I saw this but it doesn't seem to work with a scrolling collection view

Comment: Try this repository. It seems to give you the same effect you are looking for and it's written completely in swift: 
https://github.com/EzimetYusup/WormTabStrip